# Valet does not run on port - Mac/Sierra OSX

Tags: macos, laravel-valet

I installed Laravel via composer and I can run my site via Mamp and other Mac's server environments.
I installed Valet and its plugins correctly and I received a message when I type `valet` in Terminal that shows it installed correctly. But it doesn't work and I received `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` in browser.
At the end when I scan 80 port (default port) via `netstat -an | grep "\.80" | grep LISTEN` there isn't any service running on 80.

Comment: What domain name are you using for the site? Have you sanity checked your set up as described in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/valet), e.g. `ping foobar.dev`?

Comment: I use default TDL (.dev), I can ping site and all other sites with *.dev